Rearranged alternating harmonic series
Hi so i really don't know what to do with this
I have to find the sum of a rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series which equals $\ln(2)$.
It takes 2 positives then 1 negative and so on, so like this
$$1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} +\ldots$$ and so on...
What would it equal and how or why? Because i know it could be different than $\ln(2)$.

What do you mean by "i know it could be different than $\ln(2)$" ?

Using riemman series theorem i believe it could equal something different. But i dont know how to apply it

That's why you should first write the sum as $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cdots$ so we can understand the order of summation (and it'll help you).

Sorry it's my first time using the page. But I'll take it into account, thanks

See this

Hint: Using the identity $\int_0^1x^n\,dx = \tfrac{1}{n+1}$, we can write $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{4n+1}+\dfrac{1}{4n+3}-\dfrac{2}{4n+4}\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\left(x^{4n}+x^{4n+2}-2x^{4n+3}\right)\,dx$$
Now, see if you can justify switching the order of the sum and the integral.
EDIT: In particular, by writing the last term as $\tfrac{2}{4n+4} = \int_0^12x^{4n+3}\,dx$ instead of $\tfrac{1}{2n+2} = \int_0^1x^{2n+1}\,dx$, the integrand $$x^{4n}+x^{4n+2}-2x^{4n+3} = (1+x^2-2x^3)x^{4n} = (1-x)(1+x+2x^2)x^{4n}$$ is non-negative over $[0,1]$, which will allow you to justify changing the order of the summation and the integral. If you used $\tfrac{1}{2n+2} = \int_0^1x^{2n+1}\,dx$ instead, this switch wouldn't be justified, and you can end up with a different answer. Thanks @J.G. for pointing this out.

You need to subtract $\frac{1}{2n+2}=\frac{2}{4n+4}=\int_0^12x^{4n+3}dx$.
